# php.ini content type not specified

Tags: php, content-type, ini

I scanned my web application with Acunetix Web Vulnerability Scanner and it says that php.ini content type is not specified.

**Vulnerability description**

> This page doesn't set a Content-Type header value. This value informs
>   the browser what kind of data to expect. If this header is missing,
>   the browser may incorrectly handle the data. This could lead to
>   security problems.

and the suggestion it gave on "How to fix this vulnerability" is "Set a Content-Type header value for this page.
"

This is what I have in my **php.ini**

```
magic_quotes_gpc = Off;
register_globals = Off;
default_charset = "UTF-8";
memory_limit = 64M;
max_execution_time = 3600;
upload_max_filesize = 10M;
sql.safe_mode = Off;
mysql.connect_timeout = 20;
allow_url_fopen = Off;
;session.auto_start = Off;
;session.use_only_cookies = On;
;session.use_cookies = On;
;session.use_trans_sid = Off;
;session.cookie_httponly = On;
;session.gc_maxlifetime = 3600;
;session.cookie_secure =On;
;session.entropy_file = "/dev/urandom";
;display_errors = 1;
;error_reporting = E_ALL;
```

Question. How do I set a content-type header value in the php.ini file?

Comment: Why do you have your php.ini publicly exposed to the web?... You shouldn't need to set a content-type on your php.ini.  I don't understand how this is a vulnerability.

Comment: Maybe you are trying to say the files you are serving from your web browser are not setting a content-type?  Are you Apache or...?

Comment: @Clayton, dude, i goofed up. Need to update my php.ini file instead of dumping it on the application folder. Thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 1):

Check file permissions.

From the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php):

> By default, PHP will output a media type using the Content-Type
>   header. To disable this, simply set it to be empty.
>
> PHP's built-in default media type is set to text/html.

But your php.ini file is not served as a PHP page. You should not leave you php.ini file exposed to the web. More on PHP security [here](https://www.tenable.com/blog/configuration-auditing-phpini-to-help-prevent-web-application-attacks).